# Ember - displaying model value in form field

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a user settings form like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="settings">
<form class="form-horizontal user-form" {{action "update" on="submit"}}>        
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        {{input type="text" value=firstName placeholder="First Name"}}
        {{error.firstName}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        {{input type="text" value=lastName placeholder="Last Name"}}
        {{error.lastName}}
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Email Address *</label>
        {{input type="text" value=email placeholder="Email Address"}}
        {{error.email}}
    </div>
</form>
</script>
```

In my route for this page, I define the model:

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {    
        return this.store.find('user', 1);
    }
});
```

If things are left like this, the form will automatically populate with the values retrieved from the model. However, if I add a controller:

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        update: function() {
               // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

...They won't. So how do I use my model in conjunction with this controller to set the properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined your controller was as a regular `Ember.Controller` and not an `Ember.ObjectController` so the controller is not proxying the model. If you modify it to be like this:

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        update: function() {
               // Do something
        }
    }
});
```

Then it should still automatically populate with the values from the model.